# My Meteor projects skip MongoDB-startup

Tags: mongodb, meteor, startup

Three weeks ago my Meteor projects worked fine, but today I noticed that **all my Meteor projects skip the 'start-MongoDB' step**, or at least it seems that way. All my projects that rely on one or more collections now get stuck on the 'starting your app' step, while new projects start normally (probably because no MongoDB doesn't cause problems for them). Note: I'm having these problems while running applications locally on my laptop.

Most posts that I can find about apps freezing on 'starting your app' mention that the app can't connect MongoDB, which relates to my case, because it is never started, but **I don't know how to tell Meteor it should start up MongoDB first before running any of my apps**.

Any tips on this matter?

Comment: Meteor does start MongoDB first by default, you don't need to tell it so. Maybe try the `METEOR_LOG=debug` environment variable and see if you can find out more.

Comment: When I run the app afterwards it says `'Opening db file /C/Users/joosh/AppData/Local/.meteor/package-metadata/v2.0.1/packages.data.db'`
`[[[[[ C:\Users\joosh\Documents\Meteor\yolo\dockerFileTest ]]]]]` followed by `=> Started proxy.` and then a bunch of lines with `'local package version is up-to-date: <package name>'`, and then finally it keeps saying `'starting your app'`

Comment: No idea then. Try removing `.meteor/local` and `node_modules` folders. If that doesn't work, I'd reinstall Meteor. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for the tips guys, I fixed it, but the root of the problem was kind of far-fetched. The `METEOR_LOG=debug` option, as suggested by @aedm, helped me figure out what was wrong though.

One of my older applications posted the error message `Meteor 1.2.0.2 - Couldn't run tasklist.exe on Windows 10`, and when searching on that error message someone suggested that something might be wrong with my environment variables. Apparently when installing some new software a couple of days ago I created a new 'path' variable, rather than editing the old one, which overwrote the original 'path' variable, which included something essential for Meteor. I deleted the new 'path' variable, and added its contents to the old one, and now everything works and Mongo starts as it should when I run my apps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the environment variable `MONGO_URL`? If so, `meteor` (aka `meteor run`) will *not* start MongoDB.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, please provide some more information such as console output, Meteor version, Operating System and version.

Comment: I've set the `MONGO_URL` environment variable in the past, but even when I restart my command prompt MongoDB won't start for any of my Meteor apps, and shouldn't the environment variables be reset then? I'm using Windows 10 and Meteor 1.3.5.1 with applications varying between Meteor 1.3.2.4 and 1.3.5.1